# Reduce redundancy in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I am writing:

> A pattern is a set of terms, which captures a term and its surrounding terms to provide context.

Which I found that the word *term* appear too many times, is there any elegant way to reduce the redundancy and simplify the sentence?

Comment: Use synonyms of 'term' instead:
http://thesaurus.com/browse/term

Comment: A better way could be using the word you really want to say. I read your sentence and I'm not sure what do you mean by this "term". Unless you define the word "term" clearly in your writing, before this sentence in your question, I'd say your reading could be confused easily.

Comment: There's a mismatch in the plural "patterns" and the singular "a set", which could be fixed by saying "A pattern is a set …".

Comment: @DamkerngT. In computer science, terms simply means words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of one "term" by saying:

> A pattern is a set which contains a term and its surrounding terms.

But since I don't understand what the original means (a more serious problem than redundancy), this may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Suggested Answer: "Patterns provide context to a term "T" by forming a set containing "T" and its surrounding terms."**

> **ORIGINAL (without comma):**  A pattern is a set of terms which captures a term and its surrounding terms to provide context.

**DEFINITION:**  Pattern is a SetOfTerms = {TargetTerm, SurroundingTerms}
 **EQUIVALENCE:** Context(TargetTerm) := Pattern

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

> Patterns are a set of terms, which captures an item and its surrounding details to provide context.

Comment: If *term* is being treated as a technical term, the original is preferable.